# SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise won't install on Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008-r2, deployment

I've been trying to install SQL Server on a new Windows Server 2008. I have tried everything but I haven't been able to narrow down the problem.

When the installation fails I get "  Exit code (Decimal): -2068643839". The problem with this is that according to Microsoft this is a generic error code. I follow their guide to look into the detail.txt inside C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\

But I can't find something that specifies the exact error.

Any suggestions ?
Thanks in advanced.

I uploaded to detail.txt to http://www.megaupload.com/?d=0MV46SZH because it is to big to paste here.

Below is the summary.txt

```
----------
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  SQL Server installation failed. To continue, investigate the reason for the failure, correct the problem, uninstall SQL Server, and then rerun SQL Server Setup.
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068643839
  Exit facility code:            1203
  Exit error code:               1
  Exit message:                  SQL Server installation failed. To continue, investigate the reason for the failure, correct the problem, uninstall SQL Server, and then rerun SQL Server Setup.
  Start time:                    2011-02-28 11:29:56
  End time:                      2011-02-28 11:34:45
  Requested action:              Install

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  SA-SERVER
  Machine processor count:       8
  OS version:                    Windows Server 2008 R2
  OS service pack:               Service Pack 1
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 

Package properties:
  Description:                   SQL Server Database Services 2008 R2
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2008 R2
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       10
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         F:\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          ENTERPRISE

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      True
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASDOMAINGROUP:                 <empty>
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20110228_112601\ConfigurationFile.ini
  CUSOURCE:                      
  ENABLERANU:                    False
  ENU:                           True
  ERRORREPORTING:                False
  FARMACCOUNT:                   <empty>
  FARMADMINPORT:                 0
  FARMPASSWORD:                  *****
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE,BIDS,CONN,IS,BC,SDK,SSMS,ADV_SSMS,SNAC_SDK,OCS
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  HELP:                          False
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  False
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              False
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   D:\SQLServer
  INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PASSPHRASE:                    *****
  PCUSOURCE:                     
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         False
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   False
  ROLE:                          AllFeatures_WithDefaults
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 FilesOnlyMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         *****
  SECURITYMODE:                  SQL
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           SA-SERVER\Administrator
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQMREPORTING:                  False
  TCPENABLED:                    1
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  X86:                           False

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20110228_112601\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       Integration Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       Client Tools Connectivity
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       Management Tools - Complete
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       Management Tools - Basic
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       Client Tools SDK
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       Client Tools Backwards Compatibility
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       Business Intelligence Development Studio
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       Microsoft Sync Framework
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20110228_112601\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Comment: What is your install media? Have you tried another source?

Comment: Downloaded twice on two different computers from the Microsoft partner site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through trial and error I finally manage to install SQL Server.

It seems that there was something wrong with my windows installation.

These are the steps that I followed.

1) Remove SP1

2) [Install System Update Readiness Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=c4b0f52c-d0e4-4c18-aa4b-93a477456336&displaylang=en)

3) Install SP1

4) Install SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 was just released and your info shows it is installed.  I would research if RTM of SQL Server 2008 R2 supports SP1.

Note same question asked here: [Error installing SQL Server 2008 r2 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Sp1](https://serverfault.com/questions/239320/error-installing-sql-server-2008-r2-on-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1)

If Windows SP1 is the issue, I had a related issue with trying to install SQL Server 2008 RTM on Windows Server 2008 R2 RTM where "windows is newer then SQL" and one was I was able to install SQL by using a slipstream install.
http://www.fishbrains.com/2010/04/27/quickest-way-to-install-sql-2008-on-windows-server-2008-r2/

Lastly you may just want to uninstall SP1 from Windows, try SQL then.  If successful, then update SQL to latest SP And CU's before installing Windows SP1.

Comment: Interestingly enough I setup a W2008r2 box today, installed SP1 then installed SQL Server 2008r2 without any problems - so it can work.

Comment: I uninstalled the service pack and it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the test Robert Moir. At this point if it's a fresh server install I would narrow it down to a bad server install (or partial SQL install) requiring a fresh windows load, or a bad SQL install source.  Can you validate the SQL install is good by installing it on another test box?

Comment: I just finish installing inside a Hyper-V server with SP1 and it worked like a charm. The only difference is that on the main server I installed every update and PHP for IIS before installing sql server. Very strange ...